# garbage disposal unit sinktop flange is being very stubborn and won't come away

Tags: plumbing

I am replacing a garbage disposal unit in the kitchen. Everything is off but the flange, and I am getting very frustrated. I need to replace the sink flange as it doesn't fit the new unit I'm replacing the old unit with. But ... I cannot get the sink flange to loosen up, the plumbers putty is being very stubborn. Is there any way I can get that flange to come off without damaging the sink?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Is there a special nut on the bottom of that flange ? Look closely ..
If not a nice twisting motion might force it free enough to pull it up.

Answer (score 1):

I had good luck removing a stubborn strainer once with a propane torch, heating the flange portion that sticks below the sink, then tapping at it occasionally with a hammer.

If you use a mapp gas torch, be aware that sucker will heat up fast. Try to stick to propane if you don't use mapp torches much.

Also, keep a close eye on things. You may not be fighting plumbers putty at all. Might be silicone in there from a past repair, or diy install.

Comment: Obviously do not try this method on a sink that is plastic, composite, or porcelain. It might not hurt to put pb blaster or wd40 on it, not to mention plumbers putty softens with vegetable oil (but assuming its old, you might be there a while). I'd suggest using a firm wire brush if you are replacing the assembly, and if you want to avoid scratching teh underside of the sink, tape it off or use a putty knife to avoid hitting the underside of the sink itself, then try the pb blaster, let it soak give it  try.